# Seeking 1km bioclim data layers for time period between 2005 - 2009?

Tags: data, climate

I am looking to download some simple bioclim layers for a college exercise.

I am looking at annual precipitation and mean temp and want it at 1km spatial resolution for any time period around 2005 - 2009.

The worldclim website seems to indicate the 30 second data should be 1km resolution, but does not give an indication of timelines.

Can anyone point me to a link that kind of explains how and where go about this?

Comment: You may find that this is more on-topic for the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Did you check [NOAA](http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/gridded/) datasets?

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the Open Data forum. As for NOAA, no I haven't yet, and will check.